# C# WinForms Read XML File - Only Specific Nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, readxml

I have an XML File:

```
    <Database>
    <SMS>
    <Number>+447761692278</Number>
    <DateTime>2009-07-27T15:20:32</DateTime>
    <Message>Yes</Message>
    <FollowedUpBy>Unassigned</FollowedUpBy>
    <Outcome></Outcome>
    <Quantity>0</Quantity>
    <Points>0</Points>
   </SMS>
   <SMS>
    <Number>+447706583066</Number>
    <DateTime>2009-07-27T15:19:16</DateTime>
    <Message>STOP</Message>
    <FollowedUpBy>Unassigned</FollowedUpBy>
    <Outcome></Outcome>
    <Quantity>0</Quantity>
    <Points>0</Points>
    </SMS>
    </Database>
```

Currently I read it into a datagridview using this:

```
public void Read()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("SMS DataSet");
            XmlDataDocument xmlDatadoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            xmlDatadoc.DataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\RecSmsDB.xml");
            ds = xmlDatadoc.DataSet;
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            this.dataGridView1.DataMember = "SMS";
            this.dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["DateTime"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
        }
```

I want to be able to only read in the  xml objects that have a specific DateTime. Does anyone know of a way of doing this? Currently I have tried a variety of the methods included in the namespace but to no avail.

Help greatly appreciated,

regards.

***EDIT: I want to be able to dynamically change the data displayed at run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I can think of. However, you can read all the data into the DataSet, then create a DataView which filters the SMS table, and bind your grid to that instead of the DataTable.

Comment: +1 Agreed. Unless the data is prohibitively large, just filter it in the DataSet.

Answer (score 1):

What if you attach the DataSet to a BindingSource and attach this BindingSource to the grid? A BindingSource has a Filter property where you can enter SQL-like expressions.